# Como puedo hacer que se autoajuste el contenido de un modal al contenido

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, design

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera hacer es que el modal se ajuste automaticamente a lo blanco que seria el contenido no se si necesataria de javascript o no pero no se como hacer para que el contenido se incruste al contenido azul para que se vaya autoexpandiendo automaticamente

```js
//el contenido azul¡

`.ticket-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 18px;
}

.tickets {
    background-color: #191C3D;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 980px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.tickets h1{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 12px; left: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

.tickets h1::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 1px;
    width: 913%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.tickets ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px 86px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px; left: -30px;
}

//el contenido blanco
```

```js
.tickets2-container{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 230px;
    left: 28px;
}
.tickets2{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 50px;
}
.tickets2 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #7C8098;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tickets2 .id {
    position: relative;
    left: 44px; top: 0.5px; 
}

.categoria{
    position: relative;
    left: 77.5vh; top: 6px; 
}
.tickets2 .ticket-titulo{
    position: relative;
    left: 29vh; top: 6px; 
     padding-left: 0;
}

.status{
    position: relative;
    left: 83vh; top: 6px;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
}


/*.my-tickets h1::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 1px;
    width: 913%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
}*/

.my-tickets ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font: bold;
    display: inline-block;  
    color: #fff;
    position:s;
    top: 20px; left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: No contamines tus preguntas con contenido que no aporta información, si [es.so] te dice que es mucho código y necesitas texto entonces intenta explicar mejor lo que has intentado, los errores o comportamiento erróneo que tienes actualmente y un ejemplo de como debería verse. Además, cuando las preguntas tienen que ver con `HTML`, `JavaScript` y/o `CSS` puedes crear un fragmento de código interactivo (Séptimo botón de tu barra de edición de texto o presionando Ctrl + M).

Comment: "Quisiera hacer es que el modal se ajuste automaticamente a lo blanco que seria el contenido" Ponle ganas muchacho, como vas a dar esa escueta explicación